# How to pass parameters to a query on the Dao from the Repository?

Tags: android, kotlin

Dao code:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date")
    fun findTransactionsBetweenDates(from_date: Long, to_date: Long): LiveData<List<Word>>
```

Repository Code:

```
    public var  from_date: Long = 0
    public var to_date: Long = 0

    val allWordsByDates: LiveData<List<Word>> = wordDao.findTransactionsBetweenDates(from_date, to_date)

   @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
   @WorkerThread
    suspend fun WordsByDates(from_date:Long, to_date:Long): LiveData<List<Word>>  {
        return  wordDao.findTransactionsBetweenDates(from_date, to_date)
    }
```

I am suppose to observe the allWordsByDates from MyMainActivity, from there I am calling WordsByDates function through the viewModel with from and to dates, but they never change at the Repository they always 0. I tried to change the from_date and to_date from inside the WordsByDates function but that did not work, My last attempt was to  assign the return value of WordsByDates function to allWordsByDates but that didn't work too. Any help with code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like the list is not static and changes by the selection, so I would change the Repository like this:

```kotlin
    private val allWordsByDatesMLD = MutableLiveData<List<Word>>()
    val allWordsByDates: LiveData<List<Word>> = allWordsByDatesMLD

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun WordsByDates(from_date: Long, to_date: Long) {
        allWordsByDatesMLD.postValue(wordDao.findTransactionsBetweenDates(from_date, to_date))
    }
```

to work with Dao like this

```kotlin
    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date")
   suspend fun findTransactionsBetweenDates(from_date: Long, to_date: Long): List<Word>
```

Comment: It worked! You have no idea how much your solution helped me for this instance and others. Thanks a million. Apparently I can not mark it as the correct answer because I have less than 15 reputation.